# Flagged as "Rude" by bot?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, specific-question

[This answer](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/2862/285) seems to have been flagged as rude by a bot but there is nothing obviously wrong with it checking the history. No human moderation seems to have been involved.

What's going on here?

This is what I see in the revisions:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was flagged as spam (and also VLQ, as it's clearly from GPT). I validated the spam flag because the answer (and [another](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/2863/133) by the same user) is only a vehicle to include a spam link.

It's also not an answer and would have been deleted for that too, as it doesn't ever approach attempting to answer the question, and nor does the other.

Comment: Oh dear. I hope this is not the beginning of a tide of spam.

Comment: It is interesting to me that there is nothing on the revisions to indicate a human moderator was involved.

Comment: Spam flags always cause Community to delete a post when there are enough of them.

Comment: e.g. [here](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/q/1530/133) is another one deleted solely by community spam votes.

Answer (score 4):

It was flagged as spam by multiple people and consequently deleted. The only link in the answer goes to an auto parts website.

Comment: That's not what I see in the [revisions](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/posts/2862/revisions). Added picture to post.

Comment: I see I didn't check the link address. It looks possibly GPT generated but the link being wrong certainly doesn't help.

Comment: @BruceAdams typical spammer pattern is to just post a reasonable *looking* message and link a random part of it to their website. These days a lot of spammers just generated the message with ChatGPT. A post that is rather generic and has a link that doesn't show anything related is *the vast majority of time* just spam.

Comment: To be clear: the purpose isn't to trick people into clicking the link, although that could be upside from the perspective of whoever hired the spammer. From that perspective, the purpose is to boost the page rank of the link and thus make it turn up in search engines more often. The people who actually dump the spam onto the site probably don't care about much of anything, as long as they can demonstrate to their client that a link was posted.